# How to handle checkboxes inside CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter, gson

I am trying to handle 'check/uncheck' of a set of checkboxes inside a CustomArrayAdapter.

The requirement is that when I 'check' a checkbox, the other check boxes should remain checked/unchecked based on a specific condition.

The approach I am planning is that I will be storing all the 'Checkbox' objects in an ArrayList and adding them to my SharedPreferences file using 'gson'. When I 'check' a checkbox I will retrieve each one of them and change the state of the checkboxes based on my criteria.

For some reason storing a 'Checkbox' object in SharedPreferences sends the compiler into an infinite loop and I get the following stack log:

```
09-05 07:52:20.186 1560-1600/millennia.sniffbt I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-05 07:52:20.187 1560-1600/millennia.sniffbt D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-05 07:52:44.803 1560-1565/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=100KB
09-05 07:52:44.804 1560-1565/millennia.sniffbt I/art: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=100KB
09-05 07:52:44.804 1560-1565/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
09-05 07:52:46.339 1560-1567/millennia.sniffbt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.280ms
09-05 07:52:48.700 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 284903(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(1932KB) LOS objects, 37% free, 26MB/42MB, paused 4.525ms total 115.535ms
09-05 07:52:49.627 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 517140(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 31(3MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 31MB/42MB, paused 5.249ms total 97.072ms
09-05 07:52:49.976 1560-1567/millennia.sniffbt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.674ms
09-05 07:52:50.410 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 368915(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(2MB) LOS objects, 16% free, 35MB/42MB, paused 5.346ms total 90.929ms
09-05 07:52:50.804 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 293352(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(2MB) LOS objects, 13% free, 36MB/42MB, paused 5.083ms total 93.860ms
09-05 07:52:51.226 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 333422(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 19(2MB) LOS objects, 29% free, 37MB/53MB, paused 6.722ms total 178.796ms
09-05 07:52:51.813 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 602192(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 30(3MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 40MB/53MB, paused 6.137ms total 117.126ms
09-05 07:52:52.374 1560-1571/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 506509(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 24(3MB) LOS objects, 19% free, 42MB/53MB, paused 6.292ms total 112.676ms
09-05 07:52:52.605 1560-1567/millennia.sniffbt W/art: Debugger attempted to resume all threads without having suspended them all before.
09-05 07:52:52.615 1560-1567/millennia.sniffbt I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

Here is my CustomArrayAdapter

CustomArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {
    Row[] rowItems = null;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences appPrefs;

public CustomArrayAdapter(MyInterface fragmentActivity, Context context, Row[] resource) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_with_cb, resource);
    this.rowItems = resource;
    this.context = context;
    cf = new CommonFunctions();
    appPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(getContext().getString(R.string.app_shared_pref_filename), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)this.context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_with_cb, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_with_cb_Txt);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_with_cb_ChkBox);

    // Add Checkboxes into ArrayList and store em away
    ArrayList<CheckBox> arrCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    arrCheckBoxes.add(cb);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = appPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json;
    Type typeOfObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CheckBox>>(){}.getType();
    json = gson.toJson(arrCheckBoxes, typeOfObject); // MY COMPILER GOES INTO INFINITE LOOP HERE
    prefEditor.putString("ListOfChkBoxes", json);
    prefEditor.apply();

    // Create a onClickListener when a checkbox is selected
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            rowItems[position].setCB(cb.isChecked());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does storing a 'Checkbox' send the compiler into infinite loop?
2. Is there a better way to store and retrieve the checkboxes?

Comment: can store in one array and on un check remove from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was much simpler that I expected. Thanks to the comment by @Himani.

The ArrayList that I created in my getView function was alive and had all the details for me to manipulate the checkboxes even when another checkbox was checked.

Here is the code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)this.context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_with_cb, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_with_cb_Txt);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_with_cb_ChkBox);

    arrCheckBoxes.add(cb); // THIS ARRAY ALWAYS REMAINS UPDATED INSIDE ONCLICKLISTENER

    // Create a onClickListener when a checkbox is selected
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            rowItems[position].setCB(cb.isChecked());

            if(cb.isChecked()) {
                for(int iCnt = 0; iCnt < arrCheckBoxes.size(); iCnt++) {
                    if (rowItems[iCnt].isCBChecked() && !rowItems[iCnt].getDeviceAddress().equals(rowItems[position].getDeviceAddress())) {
                        if (rowItems[iCnt].getDeviceMajorClass() == rowItems[position].getDeviceMajorClass()) {
                            arrCheckBoxes.get(iCnt).setChecked(false); // THIS IS WHERE ANOTHER CHECKBOX GETS UNCHECKED IF THE CONDITION GETS SATISFIED
                            rowItems[iCnt].setCB(false);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the other answers too.

Answer (score 0):

If by Checkbox objects you mean Checkobox, the View subclass - no you cannot store them in SharedPreferences. You shouldn't even keep references pointing to them in adapter on your own. What you can do, is to keep their state in some collection instead and populate them in `onBindViewHolder()`. Then, you can store this collection of primitives in SharedPreferences using JSON or whatever serialization format you choose.